# Stripping newlines in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

What is the (or is there an) idiomatic way to strip newlines from strings in Haskell? Or do I have to craft my own by finding the trailing newlines/spaces and then removing them?

EDIT: I'm looking for what Python's rstrip does, but don't need the optional "chars" argument:

> string.rstrip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If chars
>   is omitted or None, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and
>   not None, chars must be a string; the
>   characters in the string will be
>   stripped from the end of the string
>   this method is called on.

Comment: While both your question and the various answers given deal with implementing Python's `rstrip` function in Haskell, using it is not very idiomatic in Haskell in most cases. Usually you would use `lines` and `words`, unless there is some special reason otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one simple implementation (adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28programming%29#Haskell)):

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
rstrip = reverse . dropWhile isSpace . reverse
```

There's also an `rstrip` already defined in [`Data.String.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.0.0/doc/html/Data-String-Utils.html).

(By the way, [Hayoo!](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) is a great resource for this kind of question: a search for [`rstrip`](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=rstrip) takes you directly to `Data.String.Utils`.)

Answer (score 5):

I used this the other day:

```
Prelude> let trimnl = reverse . dropWhile (=='\n') . reverse
Prelude> trimnl ""
""
Prelude> trimnl "\n"
""
Prelude> trimnl "a\n"
"a"
Prelude> trimnl "a\n\n"
"a"
Prelude> trimnl "a\nb\n"
"a\nb"
```

Comment: That's the same principle as Travis's answer.

Comment: Yes, I guess we typed at the same time. But mine does what the poster asked for! Vote for me! :)

Comment: I think trimnl = reverse. dropwhile (`elem` "\n\r\t ") . reverse would be closer to the rtrim in python

Comment: In case anyone cares, my call to elem lost the back-ticks around it when I submitted the comment.

Comment: Tim: I'm not sure what SO escape is (\`testing\` - yep it's \\), but for Haskell you can at least use flip. `trimnl = reverse . dropWhile (flip elem "\n\r\t")`.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for a typical file-reading application, then you should probably start with `lines`. This may allow you to avoid `Data.String.Utils.rstrip` completely:

```
> lines "one time\na moose\nbit my sister\n"
["one time", "a moose", "bit my sister"]
```

As you can see, `lines` takes the text of the entire file and properly turns each line into a string with no trailing newline. This means you can write a program like so:

```
main = mapM_ (putStrLn . process) . lines =<< readFile "foo.txt"
  where process :: String -> String
        process = -- your code here --
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you mean:

```
Prelude> filter (/= '\n') "foo\n\nbar\n"
"foobar"

Prelude> words "foo\n\nbar\n"
["foo","bar"]
```

But these don't deal with spaces nicely. So perhaps not what you're looking for.

Comment: Neither of these actually "strips" the string, though (in the usual sense of "remove leading or trailing characters").

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample in Chapter 4 of real world haskell which does the splitting you want. You'll need to paste the pieces back together when you are done.
http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html

Search for "Warming up: portably splitting lines of text" in the text.